# Обход блокировки telegram-бота без использования proxy и vpn

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram, virtual-hosts

Подскажите способы обхода блокировки api.telegram.org для бота. Proxy и vpn использовать не получится. Где можно найти рабочий хост для замены api.telegram.org? Или другие способы?

Comment: Просто запускаете бота на сервере, который подключен к сети, в которой не заблокирован телеграм.

Comment: зеркало api.telegram.org возможно найти?

Answer (score 2):

Размещайте вашего бота на иностранном хостинге вроде Heroku, у них телеграм никто не блокирует, поэтому бот будет работать нормально.